# How to pass a C math operator (+-*/%) into a function result=mathfunc(x,+,y);?

Tags: c

I'm writing some math routines in a C program for multi-precision integers and I want to be able to easily write expressions, but handle the math with my own function. So I want some way that lets me do this:

```
MPI x=mpi(5),y=mpi(6),z;
z=mpimath(x,+,y);
```

Is this possible in C by encoding the character somehow? I know there's no operator overloading so it has to be a function call, and the `+`-sign cannot be part of the function name.

Comment: There are overloaded operators like `-` and `/` in C. You can't add any overloads though, but that's not specific to operators but applies to functions in general.

Comment: You can pass the `+` as a character constant by enclosing it in single quotes, `z=mpimath(x,'+',y)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can interface to your function using a macro. A macro gives you extra powers over the physical appearance of the code. In particular, you can *stringify* an argument. And you can pass any complete C *token* as an argument to a macro.

So do something like this:

```
#define mpimath(X,F,Y) (mpimath)(X,#F,Y)  /* stringify F */
```

Then define your function to accept a `char *` parameter. This will result in the string `"+"` for the argument `+`. By using the same name for the macro, calls to the function are *intercepted* by this macro so a call like this:

```
mpimath(p,*,r)   /* macro invocation */
```

is expanded to

```
(mpimath)(p,"*",r)   /* function call */
```

. The parens around the function name are not strictly necessary here, since a macro is not allowed to be recursive, it will expand to the right thing. But wrapping parens is also the way to explicitly call the *function* bypassing any macro definitions, so I find it helps self-document the code to add them here.

You can use something like `char *ops="+-*/"; int op=strstr(ops, f)-ops;` to map the string to a small integer <sup>(*)</sup> which can then be used to index a function-table. Or you can dereference the string to get a `char` which you can use in a `switch`.

```
MPI mpimath(MPI x, char *f, MPI y){
    switch(*f){
    case '+': //...
              break;
    case '-': //...
              break;
    //etc.
}
```

Or you can move the dereferencing back into the macro. It looks a little weird in the macro. But I think it makes the function look nicer.

```
#define mpimath(X,F,Y) (mpimath)(X,*#F,Y) /* stringify and deref F */

MPI mpimath(MPI x, char f, MPI y){
    switch(f){
    case '+':
    //etc.
    }
}
```

---

Edit: Some details about the actual code that gave rise to this *share-your-knowledge* q/a pair.

The motivation for the passing the operator as a `char` arose indirectly, but never in the simplified form shown in the question. The current use of macro looks like this for the `+` function:

```
 BIN_MATH_FUNC(+,AV(z)[i],AV(a)[i],AV(w)[i],plusover,plusdomainI,plusdomainD)
```

and the macro also directly handles native types like `int` and `double`. So the framework that the mpi function needed to fit was already set up to distinguish operations by their actual C operator (as a macro argument). So the real situation didn't allow for the use of `enum` symbols.

---

<sub>(*) <del>This is not, to put it politely, a good way to do it. The code relies upon the compiler to condense the two strings into one location in the compiled program's string-table. This is a typical (one might even say *obvious*) optimization for the compiler to do, but is it not guaranteed by any standard. It would be better (though more verbose) to assign the string literal to a `char *` variable and use the variable in both places.</del> You can (and probably should) test the result of `strstr` for `NULL before doing anything with the result.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can also use enums:

```
enum MathOps {PLUS, MINUS, MULTIPLY}; 

MPI mathfunc(MPI x, enum MathOps operation, MPI y)
{
    switch(operation){
    case PLUS: //...
              break;
    case MINUS: //...
              break;
    case MULTIPLAY: // .... 
              break;
    //etc.
}

Call:

mathfunc(x,PLUS,y)
```

The good thing about this approach is that you can easily see at the top of the file the operations that your function will support. <strike>The compiler will also complain if you add an enum but don't add it to the switch case which can be nice.</strike>

EDIT: Live example: http://ideone.com/GCJ9ro

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to do it. I also love enums. Somehow I never get that compiler warning, probably because I usually treat them as `int` and lose the typechecking. ... You could even paste the words with a macro `#define mathfunc(x.f.y) f##func(x,y)` and `MPI plusfunc (x, y)` etc.

Comment: You are correct. I don't get that warning either. It was probably something I saw due to other syntax errors in the code before I fixed them.

Comment: I think `splint` will give you (these) warnings.